# Select number of matching rows of a particular column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

I'm looking to count the number of matching rows for each id in the below table. Although one option is to create another table which keeps track of the count of each category, I would prefer to solve this without creating a second table (ideally without a temporary table too).

My Table:

```
+---------+----------------+
| id      | category       |
+---------+----------------+
| 3611383 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA |
| 3611382 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA |
| 3611381 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA |
| 3611378 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA |
| 3611377 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA |
| 3611376 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA |
| 3611374 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA |
| 3611373 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA |
| 3611372 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBB |
| 3611371 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBB |
| 3611370 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBB |
| 3611369 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBB |
| 3611366 | CCCCCCCCCCCCCC |
| 3611365 | CCCCCCCCCCCCCC |
| 3611364 | CCCCCCCCCCCCCC |
+---------+----------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+---------+----------------+---------+
| id      | category       | count   |
+---------+----------------+---------+
| 3611383 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 8       |
| 3611382 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 8       |
| 3611381 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 8       |
| 3611378 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 8       |
| 3611377 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 8       |
| 3611376 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 8       |
| 3611374 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 8       |
| 3611373 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 8       |
| 3611372 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBB | 4       |
| 3611371 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBB | 4       |
| 3611370 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBB | 4       |
| 3611369 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBB | 4       |
| 3611366 | CCCCCCCCCCCCCC | 3       |
| 3611365 | CCCCCCCCCCCCCC | 3       |
| 3611364 | CCCCCCCCCCCCCC | 3       |
+---------+----------------+---------+
```

The closest I've gotten is

```
SELECT id, category, count(category) AS c FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But that will product only one row:

```
+---------+----------------+---------+
| id      | category       | c       |
+---------+----------------+---------+
| 3611383 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 8       |
+---------+----------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.category = t.category) as c
from mytable t;
```

An alternative is to do a `group by` and `join`.  One advantage of the correlated subquery is that it can readily take advantage of an index on `mytable(category)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!